# Add vertical space after section only if at top of the page?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Is there a way to automatically add a `\baselineskip` *after* a given `\section`, only if that section starts at the very top of a page (see MWE below)?

Note: The MWE does not include `\titlesec`. For documents with `\titlesec` requirement, see [Add vertical space after section only if at top of the page, for documents using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227801/add-vertical-space-after-section-only-if-at-top-of-the-page-for-documents-using)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\section*{Section 1}
\kant[1]

\section*{Section 2}
\kant[2]

\clearpage

%% Is there a way to have the following behaviour, automatically?

\section*{Section 3}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This adds extra vertical space if the position of `\section*{` is above some definite threshold (counted from bottom, as specified in the `zref-savepos` package. The threshold value might have to be changed at will to fit the needs.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage{zref}

\def\toptreshold{40000000}

\newlength{\ssectionaddskip}
\setlength{\ssectionaddskip}{\baselineskip}

\newcounter{dummysection}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\@ssect}{\stepcounter{dummysection}\zsaveposy{starredsectionstart::\number\value{dummysection}}}{}{}

\xapptocmd{\@ssect}{%
  \ifnumgreater{%
    \zposy{starredsectionstart::\number\value{dummysection}}}{\toptreshold}{%
    \vspace{\ssectionaddskip}}{%
    %  Do nothing, since vertical position is lower than the treshold
  }}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\section*{Section 1}
\kant[1]

\section*{Section 2}
\kant[2]

\clearpage

%% Is there a way to have the following behaviour, automatically?

\section*{Section 3}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. I am very grateful for it, and also coming to learn about packages `zref-savepos` and `zref`. I am assuming the part `{\toptreshold}{\vspace{\ssectionaddskip}}{}}{}{}` is where one would tweak the vertical space, just in case design specs would change? Thank you so much.

Comment: @gsl: Yes, the code is very compact, I will expand it a little bit... just a moment please ;-)  The threshold value should be changed by `\setlength{\ssectionaddtopskip}{...}` to an appropiate value. If you use a `\begingroup...\endgroup` you could change the value even without backing up the old value.

Comment: @gsl: Well, `titlesec` redefines a lot of `section` stuff actually

Comment: @gsl: Yes, that's better because it would change your initial question here and I assume that the `titlesec` experts will provide an answer quickly